# Automorphism group of symmetric square

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, automorphism-groups, hyperelliptic-curves, involutions

Say I have a hyperelliptic curve without any automorphism beyond the hyperelliptic involution.

Is it possible for its symmetric square to obtain new automorphisms beyond the one induced by the hyperelliptic involution?

Comment: A general $g^2_4$ on a genus $2$ curve gives an unramified morphism from the curve to a plane quartic with a single ordinary double point.  Plane quartics have an involution on their symmetric square, just by taking the residual of a degree $2$-divisor in the intersection of the quartice with the secant line.

Comment: I see now that the involution in my comment (which is, indeed, different from the hyperelliptic involution) is only defined on the open complement of a singleton: it is defined for all points in the symmetric square except a single point.  So this is a birational involution of the symmetric square, not a biregular involution.